# What angles of releasing a pendulum will affect the speed of a spherical object hit by it?

Tags: classical-mechanics, speed

I tried to search for papers for similar experiments but I couldn't find any. Could someone please help me find resources for my experiment. It would also be great if someone could give some suggestions for my research. Like the methodology I should use, fixed variables, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so what you're trying to find out is how the angle effects the speed, if you think about it an increase of angle increases the potential energy to be converted into kinetic energy. so to help start off we need to think about when the ball will be hit will it be at the bottom of the swing wor some way up to how would this affect the results can you find a theoretical equation to compare the results to. you will need to think about the momentum of the coalition because you could have energy loss in an inelastic collision. but draw a diagram and write out formulae and facts about pendulums which can help. and just follow ideas till they break in some way and try again. but questions need to be a little more specific for this site because it is difficult to give a solid answer.